# Android setonitemclicklistener implementation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, onclicklistener

I have a ArticlesAdapter which I am using to read remote JSON data. The adapter is working but I am struggling to get my ListView setonitemclicklister working.

**What I am trying to accomplish is the ability to click on a ListItem and to get the Article data for the option clicked on.
I have functions like getName() in my Article class which I need to call in response to a ListItem click but I can't seem to find a way to accomplish it.**

I am trying to do this in my AsyncTask class.

Using the following code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.i("CHECK", "RESULTS: " + result);

            List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<Article>();

            String title = null;
            String nid = null;

            try{
                for(int i=0; i < data.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject dataObj = (JSONObject)data.get(i);
                    JSONObject record = dataObj.getJSONObject("node");
                    title = (record.getString("title"));
                    nid = (record.getString("nid"));

                    Log.i("FOUND", "title: " + title);
                    Log.i("FOUND", "nid: " + nid);

                    articles.add( new Article(title, "", Integer.parseInt(nid)) );
                }
            }catch(JSONException j){
                Log.e("CHECK", "Attempting to read data returned from JSONReader: " + j.toString());
            }

            ListView articlesList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.articlesList);
            ArticleAdapter adapter = new ArticleAdapter(ArticlesActivity.this, R.layout.article_item, articles);
            articlesList.setAdapter(adapter);

            articlesList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testing : ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    Log.i("CHECK", "AdapterView: " + parent);
                    Log.i("CHECK", "VIEW : " + view);
                    Log.i("CHECK", "POSITION : " + position);
                    Log.i("CHECK", "ID : " + id);
                }
            }); 

            if(dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

My problem is I am not sure how to get the setOnItemClickListener working.
I am able to print the arguments via the Log function:

```
Log.i("CHECK", "AdapterView: " + parent);
Log.i("CHECK", "VIEW : " + view);
Log.i("CHECK", "POSITION : " + position);
Log.i("CHECK", "ID : " + id);
```

...but I get errors when I try casting any of the arguments into an Article object so I can call it's getName() function etc.

Comment: I am a little confused by your question, what exactly are you trying to accomplish in your OnItemClickListener?

Comment: Then Sam's answer is correct for what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your AsyncTask appears to be nested in your Activity, if it isn't simply pass `articles` to your Activity, then use:

```
articlesList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        Article article = articles.get(position);
        // Do something with article
    }
});
```

Comment: My AsyncTask is indeed nested in my Activity class. Moreso, the onclick listener is within the AsynchTask class. As I am fairly new to this, I am not really clear if this is the right strategy but the app still works with the exception of the onclicklistener

Comment: I tried your code but it correctly complains there is no get() function defined in my Article class

Comment: Not `article.get()` but `articles.get()`. `get()` is a method of List, so you are asking your `ArrayList<Article>` for the appropriate Article. Notice the difference?

Answer (score 0):

An architectural change you would want to do is pull your `ListView`, `Adapter`, and `OnItemClickListener` initialization out of the `AsyncTask` and only update `articles` as well as notify the `Adapter` in the `onPostExecute` callback.